# An unexpected error occurred in the .NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL

Tags: .net, postgresql, visual-studio, ado.net, npgsql

I am using Npgsql database version **9.4**  In VS-2012, I installed Npgsql **2.2.4.3 (.Net Provider for postgresql)**  and **EntityFramework 5.0.0**. I can create entity data model without any problem.

After updating to VS-2015 and I am not able to Create data model using ADO.Net
I have install **Npgsql 4.1.3.1** and **EntityFramework6.Npgsql 6.4.0** through nuget, and install **Npgsql.vsix 4.1.3.1** from Npgsql.vsix.

After installation three above components, when we try to create Entity Data Model using ADo.Net, I got the error **"An unexpected error occurred in the .NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL.** Please contact the provider vendor to resolve this problem". When the error occurred, where can we look for a clue?

**Work Procedure**

---

**Create new ADO.Net Data Model -> EF Designer from Database -> Press New Connection Button then...**
[image: Problem Creating Ado.net]

After close the error dialog and try to create new connection string again, this time the Choose Data Source dialog open.But no provider for Postgresql shows up
How to fix this problem? Thx!
[image: No Providers for postgresql]

Comment: For the Visual Studio extension (VSIX), can you please try the latest 4.0.x? There are some known issues with the 4.1 releases.

Comment: I have removed VSIX 4.1.3 version and installed 4.0. It is working now. Thanx. You saved my time